# How to create a gutter net overlay as GUI?

Tags: user-interface, autoit, sprite-sheet

I want a fullscreen GUI with a gutter net of 96x96 pixels and a small gutter border (maybe a pixel). The GUI should be a transparent overlay (just the gutter net should be displayed).

Why? I often work with sprite-sheet images (create, resize or rearrange them). I do not have software which supports gutter lines as help view. It would be great to have for a quick accurate adjustment.

I use a fullscreen GUI as `$WS_POPUP` (borderless) window. The gutter is a label with specific background color. I have to manually create these so I hope you have a better idea.

My code so far:

```
#include <GuiConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

$iGuiW = @DesktopWidth
$iGuiH = @DesktopHeight
$iGuiGutterSize = 96
$hColor = 0x00FF00

$hGui = GUICreate("", @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight, 0, 0, $WS_POPUP, $WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW + $WS_EX_TOPMOST)
; From left to right.
GUICtrlCreateLabel("", 0, 0, $iGuiW, 1)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("", 0, $iGuiGutterSize, $iGuiW, 1)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("", 0, $iGuiGutterSize * 2, $iGuiW, 1)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("", 0, $iGuiGutterSize * 3, $iGuiW, 1)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

; From top to bottom.
GUICtrlCreateLabel("", 0, 0, 1, $iGuiH)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("", $iGuiGutterSize, 0, 1, $iGuiH)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("", $iGuiGutterSize * 2, 0, 1, $iGuiH)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

GUICtrlCreateLabel("", $iGuiGutterSize * 3, 0, 1, $iGuiH)
GUICtrlSetBkColor(-1, $hColor)

GUISetState( @SW_SHOW, $hGui )

While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            GUIDelete($hGui)
            Exit
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

1. How to get the GUI to be transparent except the gutter lines?
2. How can I do it without manually setting *label* by *label* for each line (row and column)?

Yes it's like a grid design but just the borders as lines.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice:**

It's a bit unclear that my suggestion fits your imaginations, but I guess you mean something like a grid design. As you mentioned the GUI is like a overlay (transparent) and just the grid lines are visible.

The solution is in the `_createGridStructure()` function which uses some *WinAPI* functions to provide such a grid (rectangle design). I extracted your `GUIDelete($hGui)` and `Exit` in a separat function `_disposeAndExit()`. I also extracted the GUI creation part in a function to be a bit more flexible.

**Approach:**

```cpp
#include-once
#include <GuiConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Global $iGuiWidth   = @DesktopWidth
Global $iGuiHeight  = @DesktopHeight
Global $iGridSize   = 96       ; change the size if you want
Global $vGridColor  = 0x00FF00 ; change the grid line color if you want
Global $hMainGui

Func _createGui()
    $hMainGui = GUICreate( '', $iGuiWidth, $iGuiHeight, 0, 0, $WS_POPUP, $WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW + $WS_EX_TOPMOST )
    GUISetBkColor( $vGridColor )
    GUISetState( @SW_SHOW, $hMainGui )
EndFunc

Func _createGridStructure()
    Local $iGridLinesX = Floor( $iGuiWidth / $iGridSize )
    Local $iGridLinesY = Floor( $iGuiHeight / $iGridSize )
    Local $hMainRegion = _WinAPI_CreateRectRgn( 0, 0, 0, 0 )

    For $i = 0 To $iGridLinesX Step 1
        $hRegion = _WinAPI_CreateRectRgn( $i * $iGridSize, 0, ( $i * $iGridSize ) + 1, $iGuiHeight )
        _WinAPI_CombineRgn( $hMainRegion, $hRegion, $hMainRegion, 2 )
        _WinAPI_DeleteObject( $hRegion )
    Next

    For $i = 0 To $iGridLinesY Step 1
        $hRegion = _WinAPI_CreateRectRgn( 0, $i * $iGridSize, $iGuiWidth, ( $i * $iGridSize ) + 1 )
        _WinAPI_CombineRgn( $hMainRegion, $hRegion, $hMainRegion, 2 )
        _WinAPI_DeleteObject( $hRegion )
    Next

    _WinAPI_SetWindowRgn( $hMainGui, $hMainRegion )
EndFunc

Func _disposeAndExit()
    GUIDelete( $hMainGui )
    Exit
EndFunc

_createGui()
_createGridStructure()

While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            _disposeAndExit()
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Now you don't have to manually adjust the grid lines if you switch the monitor resolution.

Comment: Do not add "I hope this will help you" to your answers, as that is considered "noise" on Stack Overflow. And *certainly* don't format it as a blockquote, since it is not a quotation.